# Unity3D: Are motion captured animations alot less compatible on mobile?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, animation, optimization, mo-cap

So there is this zombie animation pack on the asset store that i want to purchase, but all the animations in the pack are motion captured, so my question is if i were to buy this pack and use it on my mobile game project would it be practical or would it heavily affect the performance ?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

It would have the same impact as a **normal animation**.

**Quality** is slight **more** than **regular** animations made in any animation program.

**What you can do to reduce the animation size and lower the quality is to:**

1. Download [Blender 2.8](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-80/) ***(is free and open source)***
2. Import the 3D Model
3. Import the Motion Capture Animation File
4. Remove Some Key Frames From the Motion Capture in the Animation Tab
5. Export Animation From Blender to FBX, or other format you want
6. Import into Unity 3D

**Resources:**

- [How To Rig Model and Motion Capture](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/07/23/how-to-motion-capture-easy-with-a-phone-radical-blender-2-8/)
- [How to 3D Motion Capture Easy and Free with a Phone!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwc9vTCLYCc)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, i will definitely go with that approach